# subl command not working on gitbash after i restart my terminal

Tags: sublimetext3, git-bash

subl command not working  whenever i restart my terminal after adding
alias 'subl="/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'
But it works on first attempt

it annoys me to write
alias 'subl="/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'  everytime whenever i have to open sublime through git bash

Comment: Consider modifying your bash `$PATH` setting to include `/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3`. See `.bashrc` and `.profile` in [the bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) (section 6.2, "bash startup files").

Comment: Where did you add the alias command? Also, are the single quotes included in the command you added?